# How to pass file path as parameter to express Router / controller

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, parameters, router

So I have been struggling for quite a long time with this. I looking display all files from a specific folder with nodeJS / Express. I have this router + controller.

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/getAll/:folder', handleGetAll);
```

And my controller looks like this

```
const handleGetImages = async (req, res) => {
    
const user = req.user;
    // Get the folder from the request
const folderPath = req.params[0];


    // Get the images from the database
    const images = await Image.find({ folder: folderPath });


    //Returning all public or user owned images

    const filteredImages = images.filter((image) => {
        // Check if the image is public or if the user owns it
        
    return image.isPublic || (image.user && image.user.toHexString() === user);
      });
      return res.json(filteredImages);

};
```

On the front end I'm using SWR to query my backend like this :

```
const {data, error, isLoading} = useSWR(['/images/getAll/'+folder, token], getImages );
```

And my getter :

```
const getImages = async (props) => {
  const [folder, token] = props;
    const response = await axios.get(BACKEND_PATH+folder, { headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token }});
    return response.data;
}
```

The problem is that I get 404 error as if my route wasn't matching properly because of the file path having "/".

Any help would be much appreciated

I have tried to encodeURIcomponent my url, by somehow it get automatically decoded by express...

Comment: Where is your `handleGetAll` function? All I can see is a `handleGetImages` function...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to pass a file path as a parameter to an Express route, and you're encountering issues because the file path contains forward slashes ("/"). By default, Express treats forward slashes in route parameters as part of the route path and not as separators. To work with file paths, you should URL encode the forward slashes in your route parameter and then decode them in your controller.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Encoding the file path on the client side (frontend) before sending the request:

```js
const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(['/images/getAll/' + encodeURIComponent(folder), token], getImages);
```

2. Decoding the file path in your Express controller:

```js
const handleGetImages = async (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  
  // Decode the folder path from the request
  const folderPath = decodeURIComponent(req.params.folder);

  // Rest of your code
  // ...
};
```

By using `encodeURIComponent` on the client side and `decodeURIComponent` on the server side, you can pass and handle file paths containing forward slashes without running into issues.

Make sure to use the `encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` functions consistently in your code to handle file paths properly when passing them as route parameters. This way, Express will correctly match the routes and handle the file paths without causing 404 errors.

Comment: Thank you, I have already tried this, but when I console.log my req.params it shows the path with '/' even though my request was made with URI encode. I can see it in the network monitor tab in my browser. It's as if express automatically decoded it. Maybe because of my other parsers ? I'm using express.json(), body-parser and cookie-parser. Any idea ? Thx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy